# Azure pipeline - specify branch name in multiple repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

As a continuation to [Azure DevOps - Handling single release for separate code repositories for UI and Dotnet API layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65000368/azure-devops-handling-single-release-for-separate-code-repositories-for-ui-and) I am trying to proceed with checking out multiple repos in my yaml by defining it under repositories as shows below. I am unable to understand where to change the branch to make sure, my tasks such as checkout does not happen on master, but on my custom branch.

```
resources: 
repositories:
  - repository: mybitbucketrepo
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: myserviceconnection
    trigger:  # CI trigger for this repository, no CI trigger if skipped (only works for Azure Repos)
      branches:
        include: [ custom-branch ]
    name: orgname/reponame
```

What I tried so far is below for which I get the error - Only 'self', 'none' or a repository alias are supported. Any help will be appreciated.

```
- checkout: mybitbucketrepo@custom-branch
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to define `ref` settings:

> When using a repository resource, specify the ref using the ref property. The following example checks out the features/tools/ branch of the designated repository.

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyGitHubRepo
    type: github
    endpoint: MyGitHubServiceConnection
    name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo
    ref: features/tools
```

and then just

```yaml
steps:
- checkout: MyGitHubRepo
```

Answer (score 2):

IT's not support to use `@`, please use inline ref syntax

```
steps:
 - checkout: self
 - checkout: git://MyProject/MyToolsRepo@features/mytools
```

By appending `@<ref>`, the agent can be instructed to check out a different ref. In this case, it's assumed to be a branch called features/mytools. Branches can also be prefixed with `refs/heads/` to make it unambiguous that it's a branch.

Other valid refs (and ref-like things):

- refs/tags/
- commit ID

For more details, please take a look at this link: [Multi-checkout: checking out multiple repos](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/multi-checkout.md)

You could also define it in resource, check our official doc --[Checking out a specific ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checking-out-a-specific-ref) A sample as below:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: app
    type: github
    name: org1/repoA
    ref: master
    endpoint: 'GitHub endpoint'
    trigger:
    - master
    - release/*
```